# Using wood chippings to cover potatoes

Tags: potatoes

Our allotment has teamed up with a tree surgeon for a constant supply of fresh wood chippings from trees he trims/removes.

Having taken use of this to cover all the paths in my allotment I have dug my potatoe trenches (I usually go a spade and a half down and then cover as green appears) and am now wondering if instead of recovering with soil I could make use of the chippings to cover the potatoes making it easier for me later in the year to dig potatoes up. I can then dig this into the whole bed in winter to mix with the soil.

I have read of straw being used to cover potatoes are there any risks to using fresh wood chippings, are there types of trees that would be dangerous to grow food in due to natural toxins?